# Have to restart docker every ddev stop

Tags: docker, ddev, craftcms

I'm just starting out playing with DDEV and hit an annoying roadblock.

It doesn't matter if I'm adding a new project or running `ddev start` on an existing, the project will only start and be accessible the first time after a docker restart. If I restart docker, run `ddev start` on a site, leave it running for a short time then `ddev stop`. I have to restart docker to then run `ddev start` again.

In the terminal, after starting then stopping a site, I run `ddev start` again and can see ddev run through the steps of creating/re-creating the containers but stops at different points each attempt. If I do a CTRL+C then run `ddev start` again, another container will get recreated.
I can only do 2 starts and the process will always stop at a `Container ddev-projectname-web Recreated` line.

The only difference I can see after restarting docker, then running `ddev start` on the same project, is

> Network ddev_default created

Shows on the first line, followed by

> Container ddev-ssh-agent  Started

I then get

> ssh-agent container is running: If you want to add authentication to the ssh-agent container, run 'ddev auth ssh' to enable your keys.

The containers then start (dba, db, web). I get a couple of warnings with the same text:

> Project type has no settings paths configured, so not creating settings file.
> I can't find much that relates to this message and what I'm experiencing.

The site is then accessible. Running `ddev stop` then `ddev start` after gets stuch up to the web container recreating.

There are no messages in docker as the containers don't start. I've done a factory reset on docker which made no difference and I've cleared all images as per the support docs.

Any help around? I moved to Craft Nitro so I wouldn't have to fight MAMP each day but now Nitro has been abandoned and now DDEV is being pushed.

Comment: I can help you more easily if you say what environment you're on. I can guess you're on macOS because you mention MAMP. But I can help a lot more if you do a `ddev debug test` and put the results in a gist on gist.github.com and share the link here or elsewhere. You'd get faster help in Discord, https://discord.gg/hCZFfAMc5k - we can help you there much more interactively. Troubleshooting docs are at https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/basics/troubleshooting/

Comment: `ddev logs` may help you understand what's going on, but I haven't heard of anything like this before.

Comment: @rfay - apologies, yes I'm on MacOS (although MAMP is available on Windows too :) )
I'll do a gist and share on here today. I've tried joining the Discord from the DDEV site and your link and both say "Unable to accept invite" (tried from different devices to make sure it's not this laptop).
I did try the docs and couldn't see anything to match my issue. I don't get any obvious errors but I will check the logs.

Comment: I can't run `ddev logs` as "Project is not currently running". Tried `ddev start` then opened a new terminal to the same project and tried logs there but got the same error.

Comment: To join Discord, please try logging out from discord first and see if that works for you. If it doesn't try logging in and then using it. I'd love to hear your experience. This link might work better too, please let me know your experience, https://discord.gg/kDvSFBSZfs

Comment: If `ddev logs` doesn't work use `docker logs ddev-<projectname>-web` after you've done the start and given up on it and hit <ctrl-c>.